# UIAlertController with Custom UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to use a custom UITextField, more precisely AKMaskField( [here is AKMaskField project on GitHub](https://github.com/artemkrachulov/AKMaskField) )

But I had no luck, here is my code, a simple UIAlertController:

```
 @IBAction func buttonClick(sender: AnyObject) {

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Vincular CPF", message: "Digite seu CPF para acumular mais pontos no seu programa de fidelidade (Somente números)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(textFieldConfig) //Line with error
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: handleCancelButton))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Enviar", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
            (UIAlertAction) in
            println("ok")
        }))



    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: {


    })

}

func textFieldConfig(textField: AKMaskField){
    textField.mask = "{ddd}.{ddd}.{ddd}-{dd}"
    textField.maskTemplate = "x"
    textField.maskShowTemplate = true

    //textField.keyboardType = .NumberPad
    //textField.placeholder = "00000000000"
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
 Cannot invoke 'addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler' with an argument list of type '((AKMaskField) -> ())'
```

The error is pretty clear, and I tried everything to force a downcast to an UITextField but nothing seems to work.

Anybody have any idea how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try making another function:

```
let config = {(textField: UITextField) in textFieldConfig((textField as? AKMaskField)!)}
alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(config) //Line with error
```

Comment: I had to change to `(textField: UITextField!)` to compile and when I click the button I get this error message: Could not cast value of type '_UIAlertControllerTextField' (0x109a40b88) to 'Test___iOS_Application.AKMaskField' (0x106ce6e60).

Comment: So `AKMaskField` does not extend `UIAlertControllerTextField`? Can you modify it so that it does?

Comment: I tried to extend it but I get an error: Use of undeclared type 'UIAlertControllerTextField'

Comment: I forgot that `UIAlertControllerTextField` is private. You'll have to do the customization manually (i.e. in the configuration handler, by copy/pasting code from `AKMaskField`.

Answer (score 0):

This won't compile because the `UIAlertController` is instantiating a `UITextField`. There is no public interface that I can find to allow you to replace is with a custom class like `AKMaskField` - however you can set the delegate in the configuration handler and customize it from there.

Comment: And how would I do that? I'm kinda new to swift